# NullReferenceException on a PropertyChangedEvent by bidirectional communication with a TextBox (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

Error Message:

> HResult=0x80004003   Message=The object reference was not set to an
> object instance.   Source=System.Windows.Forms   StackTrace:    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetPropValue(Object value)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PushData(Boolean force)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PushData(Boolean& success)
> at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyManager.OnCurrentChanged(EventArgs ea)
> at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.PropValueChanged(Object sender,
> EventArgs e)    at
> System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object
> component, EventArgs e)    at
> System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object
> component, EventArgs e)
>
> at
> System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnINotifyPropertyChanged(Object
> component, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
> System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
> sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
> projectXYZ.MVVM.ViewModel.RecipeViewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged(String
> propertyName) in ~\ViewModel\RecipeViewModel\RecipeViewModel.cs:line
> 132
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> projectXYZ.MVVM.ViewModel.RecipeViewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged(string)
> in RecipeViewModel.cs

EDIT:
Line 132: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Aim:

In a WinForm display a Recipe Editor, where you can select a category,  then select the recipe to change and change a Recipe also with some nested attribute  objects (oven temperature and time ramping etc.) layers/steps.

Use:

1. Select a Category in a displayed ComboBox1
2. Select a Recipe in a displayed ComboBox2

This selected Recipe should displayed in some Textboxes, Comboboxes and some specific steps are shown in a DatagridView. Also it should be change able and not loosing it's information if you select another Recipe in ComboBox2.

Problem:
See above Exception.

---

Here is a part of the code (I hope I didn't forget something from c&p and translation):

I have a CollectionViewSource RecipesOnWork, which I'm filtering with a CategoryFilter, which works good.
I give this filtered View to a combobox, `RecipesOnWork.Cast<RecipeViewModel>().ToList()`, where I can now select a Recipe by it's Name.
I was not able to find a better way... (If there is one I would like to read it  but that is not for this question)

I also hook me on the Event CollectionViewSource.CurrentChanged:
`RecipesOnWork.View.CurrentChanged += CurrentRecipeChanged;`

With a selected Recipe from the ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged Event I check if the Recipe is in RecipesOnWork find the Recipe in RecipesOnWork set this on CurrentItem:

```
if(sender is ComboBox combobox)
        {
            combobox.SelectedItem is RecipeViewModel Recipe
            if (RecipesOnWork.View.Contains(Recipe))
            { RecipesOnWork.View.MoveCurrentTo(Recipe); }
        }
```

Because of CurrentRecipeChanged I set my private CurentSelectedRecipe
Becaus of my implamantation of

```
    private RecipeViewModel curentSelectedRecipe = new RecipeViewModel();

    public RecipeViewModel CurentSelectedRecipe
    {
        get { return CurentSelectedRecipe; }
        set 
        {
            // Edit:
            if (curentSelectedRecipe == value || value == null)
            { return; }
            //Even if I deactivate this part of unsubcribe I get the exception.
            if (curentSelectedRecipe != null)
            { curentSelectedRecipe.PropertyChanged -= InformRecipeChanged; }
            curentSelectedRecipe = value;
            //Even if I deactivate this part of subcribe I get the exception.
            curentSelectedRecipe.PropertyChanged += InformRecipeChanged;
        }
    }
```

and inform all possible views about the change. (Views is a list of the views)

```
Views.ForEach(view => view.OnNext(Recipe));} 

public override void OnNext(RecipeViewModel value)
        {
            ViewModel = value;
            // Work fine in the test:
            ClearSubscribe(FRM.TBNestedOBJ1Time, "Text", ViewModel.nestedOBJ1, nameof(NestedClassViewModel1.Time), true, OnPropertyChanged);
            // If I'm changing the text here I get a System.NullReferenceException:
            ClearSubscribe(FRM.TBRecipeName, "Text", ViewModel, nameof(RecipeViewModel.Name), true, OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void ClearSubscribe(Control control, string binderPropertie, object obj, string objPropertie, bool formatEnabling, DataSourceUpdateMode updateMode)
        {
            control.DataBindings.Clear();
            control.DataBindings.Add(binderPropertie, obj, objPropertie, formatEnabling, updateMode);
}
```

NestedOBJ1 has also INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class RecipeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    //Example for one nested class NestedOBJ1:
    private NestedClassViewModel1 nestedOBJ1 = new NestedClassViewModel1();
    public NestedClassViewModel1 NestedOBJ1
    {
        get => nestedOBJ1;
        set
        {
            if (nestedOBJ1 == value)
            { return; }
            nestedOBJ1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string name = "Undefined";
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if (name == value)
            { return; }
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**I have to use .Net Framework 4.8 and WinForm.**
I'm trying to implement the MVVM pattern with a little tweak So I decided to have a kind of mix of a MVC and MVVM...
=> I have Controller, VieModels, Views and Models with some business logic where I give the objects between around. Because of that maybe I lost also the PropertyChanged?

If I go step by step through the changing of Recipe.Name I can see, that Recipe.Name has already the new value, this is also not null at that moment.

- Only the EventHandler PropertyChanged could be null?
  I don't get it why I get a NullReferenceException, when I'm checking it is not null? (`PropertyChanged?.Invoke()`)
- Is this because in the first check it was not null and because of my ClearSubscribe() I get the null exception?
- And how I can avoid that if I want a bidirectional communication?
- And why it is not crashing on the nested object?

I'm sure that I'm missing something and I don't get it.
Maybe somebody could help me?

I'm trying to solve this since 5 or 6 days so I have no clue anymore how this could be done or maybe done better.

Thank you for your help.

What I tried so far was also:
To bind it manualy to the Textbox in the OnNext Method via

```
    FRM.CategoryName.TextChanged -= ManualBound;
    FRM.CategoryName.Text = ViewModel.Rubrik;
    FRM.CategoryName.TextChanged += ManualBound;
```

Where ManualBound:

```
private void ManualBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox box)
    {
        ViewModel.Category = box.Text;
    }
}
```

This works, but I have to do a lot of whiring this up, that is why I was using `ClearSubscribe(Control control, string binderPropertie, object obj, string objPropertie, bool formatEnabling, DataSourceUpdateMode updateMode)`, that was for me a "smarter" way after some research on binding some properties on a `TextBox`.

---

To find the issue:

On suggestion of @Selvin Edit in `public RecipeViewModel CurentSelectedRecipe`

```
set 
{
    if (curentSelectedRecipe == value || value == null)
    { return; }
    //Even if I deactivate this part of unsubcribe I get the exception.
    if (curentSelectedRecipe != null)
    { curentSelectedRecipe.PropertyChanged -= InformRecipeChanged; }
    curentSelectedRecipe = value;
    //Even if I deactivate this part of subcribe I get the exception.
    curentSelectedRecipe.PropertyChanged += InformRecipeChanged;
}
if (curentSelectedRecipe == value ) 
{ return; }
```

I added that and I got still this System.NullReferenceException

In the NotifyPropertyChanged method:
// was not helping:
if(PropertyChanged == null)
{ return; }

```
    if (PropertyChanged!= null)
    {
        foreach (PropertyChangedEventHandler subscriber in PropertyChanged?.GetInvocationList())
        {
            if (subscriber != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(subscriber.Target.ToString());
                    /*
                    Output: 
                    System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor
                    System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor
                    System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor
                    */
            }
        }
        
    }

    var myEvent = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName); // was not null
    var this2 = this;// was not null
    // still throw Exception.
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this2, myEvent);
```

Comment: Your exception is thrown at \ViewModel\RecipeViewModel\RecipeViewModel.cs:line 132 - which line in your code is 132?

Comment: and what would happend if you do `CurentSelectedRecipe = null` ? you will end with `null.PropertyChanged += InformRecipeChanged`

Comment: @draz I eddited the Post - but for you it is this line of code:

```PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));```

Comment: @Selvin , I try to recap your comment, if I set my CurentSelectedRecipe to null I will end up with this exception, because my code is trying to inform null? So I should check if the value is null before setting a CurentSelectedRecipe? Edit: `if (curentSelectedRecipe == value || value == null) { return; }` I added that and I got still this System.NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment of @Selvin, I got my mind on the right path of thinking so I think I found my own mistake:

```
public override void OnNext(RecipeViewModel value)
{
    if (value == null || ViewModel == value)
    { return; }
    //...
}
```

**|| ViewModel == value** was the important part.

Because everything is wired up, it does not have to rewire anything --> so don't interrup there.

My mistake was as I asked:

- Is this because in the first check it was not null and because of my
  ClearSubscribe() I get the null exception?

I didn't know to avoid that, so I tried the code above and it was doing the trick.
So the problem was changing the `PropertyChanged`, while it is changing it in his own call, where it get to null, that is how I passed the NullCheck. (`(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`)